# logging errors with flask

Tags: python, oop, decorator, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to log an error in a decorator function using `app.logger.error('')`, but it just doesn't work. In addition I cant debug this well and I can only see the response from the http client:

*(I'm using nginx+uwsgi+flask)*

> HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
>
> Server: nginx
>
> Date: Sun, 12 Aug 2012 15:45:09 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Content-Length: 14
>
> Connection: keep-alive

Everything works great with out the line: `app.logger.error('panic !!!')`

```
def mydecorator():
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                ip = Mytable.query.filter_by(ip=request.remote_addr).first()
            except:
                app.logger.error('panic !!!')
            else:
                dootherthing()

            resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            h = resp.headers
            h['add-this-header'] = ":)"
            return resp
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator
```

It seems that it is out of context or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in fact, the decorator wasnt able to detect the app instance out of context, i solve this using current_app:

1st. Import the method: `from flask import current_app`

2nd. append any app class to current_app:  `current_app.logger.error('panic !!!')`

> info @ http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.current_app
>
> "Points to the application handling the request. This is useful for
>   extensions that want to support multiple applications running side by
>   side. This is powered by the application context and not by the
>   request context, so you can change the value of this proxy by using
>   the app_context() method."

Answer (score 0):

Is `app` defined anywhere in the script that you've posted?

Also, to help with debugging, when testing you should consider using the `run()` method with [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode).

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: i cant, the flask app uses environ vars from nginx and when i run it in debug mode it freezes

Comment: @Alvarolm: Perhaps you should consider redesigning the application so that you can run the app using a script from the command line. This will allow you to run in debug mode for testing purposes. Otherwise, you will be spending a lot of time trying to debug code without a clear idea of what is wrong.

Comment: @Alvarolm: I would recommend fixing the app.debug issue first, then moving on to your other issues. Having debug mode is going to help you.